# Java Web Application Deployment

Tags: java, azure

I am trying to deploy my java web application to Azure using FTP.  Is the .war file enough to be uploaded? Or all the project files have to be uploaded?

Comment: Where are you deploying: Web app?

Comment: Azure. Fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that .war file is enough, because in that file you have everything that your java web application need, like the java classes, servlets, static web pages, etc, as you can see in this example, opening the war file:
[war file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTtCO.png)

In fact, when we use, for example, the Tomcat server, that's the only thing that the server use for running the web application.

I hope I have helped you!

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how do I access specific pages from the URL, for example, a specific html or jsp page?

Comment: For routing your pages, you need to configure that on your web.xml file, that's on the WEB-INF folder. I don't know if you are using any framework, like Spring or something, to handle your request from the browser. Here is some information that I think that might be helpful for you to understand some concepts and how to use them: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml